Azure Data Factory - SharePoint List connection issue
I'm connecting ADF to sharepoint site to collect data from multiple sharepoint lists.
Connector is working perfectly fine - ADF can get data from 2 lists stored on this sharepoint but one of them is causing the issue.
This is the error message:
An error occurred while sending the request.
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

I did all the basic troubleshooting: removing connector, establishing new one, checking if my AD group is having access to the list.

It seems that the error you are facing is primarily due to outdated or old TLS version in your SharePoint online list. Kindly try enable TLS support for your sharepoint.
Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/security-for-sharepoint-server/enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-support-in-sharepoint-server-2019
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/security-for-sharepoint-server/enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-support-in-sharepoint-server-2016?source=recommendations
